# Disabling /page/## links in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type

Every page in  my wordpress site accepts a /page/ parameter on the end of the URL so where I want:

```
www.mysite.com/page-slug
```

I'm also gettign hits on

```
www.mysite.com/page-slug/page/10 and www.mysite.com/page-slug/page/333 and www.mysite.com/page-slug/page/22
```

I've been digging through Wordpress and can't find where they come from or how to disable them and just have the permalink.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to the Dasboard of your wordpress website and Place your mouse over "Setting" at the Left Sidebar. Now please click "Settings - > Permalinks".

Now under "Common Settings". Please select radio button which says "Post name".

Comment: yes, as I said I use permalinks already. What I canlt understand or get rid of is the fact that adding /page/## (where the ## is a number) to the perma link works as a valid URL.

Comment: What do you want your permalinks look like? Do you only want this:
www.mysite.com/about-us

Comment: The permalinks are not the probelm. The problem is that you can add /page/99999 on the end of the permalink and it still works as a valid page. It sholuld got to a 404 as www.mysite.com/about-us/page/99999 doesn't exist. I assume this is some sort of pagination in wordpress but I can't see an example of it exisitng on another site or see where it has come from.

Comment: I have checked all my wp sites. almost all have same issue. I will check for the solution. If found any solution. i will paste at here.

Comment: Horalnd you're right.
 /page/99999 is the rewrite for the wordpress pagination.
You can find the code you are looking for in the WP_Rewrite class @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rewrite/